# I want to echo the highest 5 values of an array individually using sort

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, key, echo

```
<?php
$ranks = array(
"Alex 1"    =>" $team0",
"Alex 2"    => "$team1",
"Dave 1"    => "$team2",
"Dave 2"    => "$team3",
"Grant 1"   => "$team4",
"Grant 2"   => "$team5",
"Jason 1"   => "$team6",
"Jason 2"   => "$team7",
"Jessica 1" => "$team8",
"Jessica 2" => "$team9",
"Kevin 1"   => "$team10",
"Kevin 2"   => "$team11",
"Kris 1"    => "$team12",
"Kris 2"    => "$team13",
"Mark F 1" => "$team14",
"Mark F 2" => "$team15",
"Mark P 1" => "$team16",
"Mark P 2" => "$team17",
"Tim 1"     => "$team18",
"Tim 2"     => "$team19",
"Travis 1" => "$team20",
"Travis 2" => "$team21",
"Trevor 1" => "$team22",
"Trevor 2" => "$team23");
ksort($ranks);
foreach($ranks as $key => $val) {echo " ( $key ... $val\n pts ) ";}
?>
```

Instead of echoing all of the results, I want to echo the highest 5 results like into an html table row with each result in its own ...

Comment: check out [array_slice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php).  You'll want something like: `foreach(array_slice($ranks, -5) as $key => $val) { ... }`

Comment: You mean the last 5 values of the sorted array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go!

```
// Sort by value descending, while maintaining key association
uasort($ranks, function($a,$b) {
    return $a < $b ? -1 : ($a == $b ? 0 : 1);
});

// Get top 5 results
$top5 = array_slice($ranks, 0, 5);

// Display results in a table
echo "<table>";
foreach($top5 as $key => $val) {
    echo "<tr><td>$key</td><td>$val pts</td></tr>\n ";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: +1 for array_slice, no need to check if the array has less than 5 rows.  Also your missing some closing quotes.

Comment: Thanks, added the closing quotes.  Yeah, need to use `array_slice` here because it's an assoc array, so he needs to use `foreach` to get the key.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Genius!

Comment: Cheers, Kris.  By the way, I don't think you want ksort... I think you're looking for uasort() for custom sorting by value (while maintaining key association) e.g.: `uasort($ranks, function($a,$b) { return $a == $b ? 0 : ($a < $b ? -1 : 1)});`

Comment: @KrisHoward I don't see how you get the highest values first by doing `ksort()`; shouldn't it be `rsort()` instead?

Comment: Edited my example above to add `uasort()` and comments

Comment: `arsort()` will be a better choice.

Comment: I used arsort. It was exactly what I needed. Thank you everyone. Awesome responses.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $ranks = array(
    "Alex 1"    =>" $team0",
    "Alex 2"    => "$team1",
    "Dave 1"    => "$team2",
    "Dave 2"    => "$team3",
    "Grant 1"   => "$team4",
    "Grant 2"   => "$team5",
    "Jason 1"   => "$team6",
    "Jason 2"   => "$team7",
    "Jessica 1" => "$team8",
    "Jessica 2" => "$team9",
    "Kevin 1"   => "$team10",
    "Kevin 2"   => "$team11",
    "Kris 1"    => "$team12",
    "Kris 2"    => "$team13",
    "Mark F 1" => "$team14",
    "Mark F 2" => "$team15",
    "Mark P 1" => "$team16",
    "Mark P 2" => "$team17",
    "Tim 1"     => "$team18",
    "Tim 2"     => "$team19",
    "Travis 1" => "$team20",
    "Travis 2" => "$team21",
    "Trevor 1" => "$team22",
    "Trevor 2" => "$team23");

    ksort($ranks);

    $table = "<table>";
    $index = 0;
    foreach($ranks as $key => $val) 
    { 
      if(index < 5)
        $table .= "<tr><td>$key</td><td>$val pts</td></tr>";
      else
       break;

     index++;
    }

    $table .= "</table";

    echo $table;

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY

```
asort($ranks);
$input = array_unique($ranks,SORT_NUMERIC);
array_splice($input , 5); 
echo "<table>";
foreach($input as $k => $v) {
  echo "<tr><td>$k</td>
            <td>$v pts</td>
        </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

**References:**

[`asort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)

[`array_uniuqe`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

[`array_splice`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)